# Проверка Email на существование

Tags: email

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда хостинг блокирует отправку писем с сайта из-за отправки на несуществующие адреса. Мне предложили воспользоваться зарубежными сервисами проверки типа neverbounce.com, www.emaillistverify.com, www.datavalidation.com, но они платные. И каждый день проверять адреса обойдется в круглую сумму.

Так же я попробовал воспользоваться epochta verifier, что разочаровало меня, так как примерно 20% несуществующих адресов, как показала программа, все же существуют.

Пробовал online сервисы, типа 2ip.ru/mail-checker/ и подобные. Результат очень печальный. Они показывают обратное, что почти все введенные email адреса существуют, даже когда вводишь полную кашу.

Возможно поможет решение удалить адреса, если приходят письма вроде таких
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя хостинг, говорит, что это мало что даст, лучше сервисами пользоваться.

Вопрос: **каким способом пользуетесь Вы для проверки существования email адресов?**

Прикреплю скриншот для демонстрации работы разных сервисов + ответ хостинга (на ответ LANSELOT)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хороший вопрос, нужно апнуть, потому что редко нужны именно проверки на существования Email адресов.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич хостинг блокирует, поэтому нужно что-то решать.

Comment: возможно банально, но зачем отправлять почту на несуществующий адрес ?

Comment: @Alex пользователь зарегистрированный на сайте более года назад удалил свой сайт или email, тем самым email становится не существующий.

Answer (score 1):

Заранее проверить адрес на существование нельзя.

Возьмите почтовый сервис, который умеет возвращать информацию о bounce (например Amazon SES), и по приходу нотификации о bounce вычёркивайте получателя из базы пользователей

Comment: Если больше вариантов не будет, то это решение как вариант, но нужно проверять и пробовать.

Comment: И судя по моему первому скриншоту, мне приходят письма с ответом, что сообщение не доставлено. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что сообщение не доставлено, а соответственно можно удалять его из базы.

Comment: @Владимир да, только в случае Amazon SES (и других подобных сервисов, типа SendGrid) вместо письма можно получать от сервиса POST-запрос с данными об ошибке доставки - т.е. можно удалять пользователя автоматом. При этом сервисы обычно сами перестают отправлять письма на битые адреса после какого-то количества попыток.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить следующий вариант:

1. В каждое письмо добавлять пиксель 1x1 с уникальной ссылкой, по которой можно будет отличить адресата;
2. Писать обращение к этим адресам в отдельный **access.log**;
3. Периодически парсить этот лог и удалять из рассылки email адреса, по
   которым не происходит обращений.

Пример для **nginx** (модуль **ngx_http_empty_gif_module** ):

```
location = /ckeck-email/_.gif {
    access_log logs/access-check-email.log combined;
    empty_gif;
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю это реализация не на PHP? Не понял логику работы.

Comment: @Владимир приведенный выше пример — это часть конфигурации для веб-сервера nginx. На php (или другом ЯП который вы используете) вам предстоит лишь спарсить полученный лог

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но Ваш вариант не подойдет именно для меня, так как у меня простой хостинг. Ответ хостинга добавил в своем вопросе в скриншоте 2.